# Visual Studio 2015 bracing doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, braces

In Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 I could write:

```
public void Foo()
```

And then write left brace + enter and i received:

```
public void Foo()  
{  
  | <- My cursor's position  
}
```

But in Visual Studio Community 2015 if I do it too fast i will receive:

```
public void Foo() { }  
| <- My cursor's position
```

I tried to reset settings, change settings in text editor  and import settings from VS 2013 but it didn't help.

Everything is ok if I wait something like 0.5 sec after writing "{" and then put enter.
Do you know where is a problem?

I'm sorry if my english isn't correct.

Comment: Sounds like a system performance issue, I know VS2015 is slower on my 6 core, 12 thread Xeon with 32 GB of RAM than VS2013

Comment: I get that a decent amount, have to wait half a second or so before pressing TAB to wait for intellisense to pick it up

Comment: are you using resharper?

Comment: I had some issues with VS2015 (but different ones) when I updated it from an RC version, after a fresh windows install it started to work properly :)

Comment: Have the same issue and I'm not using Resharper. This happens on 2 machines that I use and can confirm, if I wait for half a second, it works properly.

Comment: No, I'm not using Reshaper. I had the problem on Windows 8.1 too(now Windows 10).

Comment: Obviously the solution to get the new Skylake processor and overclock it 5 GHz. It's a conspiracy between Microsoft and Intel.

Comment: I had that problem with Resharper and I found it impossible to use - kept tripping over it, undoing and making the same error (I type fairly fast).  If a product feature cannot keep up with something as basic and fundamental as typing then it is no use IMHO

Comment: I'd try disabling all extensions and any "interactive" features that might cause slowdowns if they aren't working properly (like maybe CodeLens) to see if any of those are the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

It works on my system. I am running Windows 10 and VS 2015 REL version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL, without any extra tools.

After a brief investigation the autocomplete uses the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.BraceCompletion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.bracecompletion.aspx) Namespace and there is a ["PreTab" method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.bracecompletion.ibracecompletionsession.pretab.aspx) that might be fun to investigate.

One way to investigate would be to install the [Visual Studio Extensibility Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb166441(v=vs.140).aspx), and try some new things like maybe using the PreTab to implement some helper to save you key strokes.

Another way would be to check out the Visual Studio Extensibility Samples on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples.